# Can there be a tag synonym for 'plot-explanation'?

Tags: support, tags

I want to use something shorter than using *plot-explanation' all the time, and I want to start using the tag synonym *conspiracy* which means basically means 'plot'.

I have checked the tag synonyms and it is not there.

**Can someone make a tag synonym for** *conspiracy*?

Comment: Conspiracy means 'plot' in the sense of 'a secret plan' not the events of a novel play or movie.

Comment: Again, if you want to just type "plot", then please do so and see what magic starts to happen.

Answer (score 5):

No.

This is not what tag synonyms are for.

Tag synonyms are used when two terms are used interchangeably for the same thing. **Nothing** about the word "conspiracy" means "plot explanation". They're utterly different.

I don't understand why you need something shorter... type "plot" and pick the one you want out of the tag picker. You don't need to type the entire tag name. In fact, with only "p" it's the first option that comes up, so you only need to type a single letter to get this tag added to a word.